# Count content of column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i have a database that looks like this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d1e12/5
When i do it in a php code

```
<?php
$q1 = "SELECT SUM(*) FROM qbd";
$r1 = $db1->query($q1);
print_r($r1->errorInfo());

foreach ($r1 as $row){
    echo $row['Dragon_Bones'];
}    
?>
```

Then this is my errorinfo result :

> Array (
>       [0] => 00000
>       [1] => 
>       [2] =>  )

Now the problem is that it is not showing the "16" result. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're selecting one column, `SUM(*)`, from the table; `Dragon_Bones` isn't in there at all. Maybe try `SELECT SUM(*) AS total FROM qdb`, and then `echo $row['total']` at the end. Also, since you're getting one single row back with your SELECT, there's no need for a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to print a column called Dragon_Bones, which is not in your resultset. If you give your output column an alias, then it will work. More to the point I guess, is that your query only returns 1 row and one column, so you don't need the for_each OR the alias.. You could just do:

```
<?php
  $q1 = "SELECT SUM(*) FROM qbd";
  $r1 = $db1->query($q1);
  print_r($r1->errorInfo());

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r1);
  print_r($row);
?>
```

Comment: @Kev30 Is asking: What am i doing wrong? This is not a good explanation.

Comment: I would have thought that was obvious from the the answer. But have added an explanation anyway.

Comment: this is the error :  `:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ` Also the dragon_bones is a column name. there are more column names. the second is Royal_dragonhide. When its working how do i use the same query for a second column?

Comment: You don't really need the foreach at all, because your query can only ever return 1 row. But apart from that, you're missing a fetch from the resultset. As for using other column names, just make it generic by using any old name.. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven'y assign alias. please assign alias as a `count`. It will definitely work

```
 <?php
        $q1 = "SELECT SUM(*)  as count FROM qbd";
        $r1 = $db1->query($q1);
        $row = $r1->fetch_row();
        echo  $row[0];
   ?>
```

Comment: Getting this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object in`

Comment: @Kev30 remove print_r($r1->errorInfo()); from your code for temporary. and try again

Comment: Now i'm getting this error : `:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in `

Comment: @Kev30 please updated code using remove foreach loop

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in` on the fetc_row line also the  table name is qbd the column name is dragon_bones but the * is for all the columns in the table

Comment: @Kev30 sorry there was an issue with alias. Try the new code

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print something that's not in your array. Try this:

```
$q1 = "SELECT SUM(*) as total FROM qbd";
$r1 = $db1->query($q1);

foreach ($r1 as $row){
    echo $row['total'];
}
```

Comment: GGetting this error : `:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in`